# How can I retrieve a collection of file locations if I give the method a location of the parent folder?

Tags: c#, windows, file

For example, given the folder: C:\images\a

How could I retrieve a collection of all of the images in that folder? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For just simple string paths, you can use the `GetFiles` static method in the `Directory` class (`System.IO`).

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

For more information about the files, you could use the `DirectoryInfo` class to retrieve `FileInfo` objects about each file.

```
FileInfo[] fileInfos = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles("*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx).

If you want to recursively search subfolders, pass `SearchOption.AllDirectories`.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you could do it is:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:/demos");
 FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.jpgs");
 foreach(FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
 {
  //do your stuff       
 }
```